# Why gridApi.onFilterChanged() event redirect the page

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a button to respond to filter function

```
<div class="col-md-1">
     <button (click)="applyFilter()" class="btn btn-primary"
     style="float: right;">Search</button>                     
</div>    


applyFilter() {
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
}

isExternalFilterPresent(): boolean {
    return true;
}

doesExternalFilterPass(node: RowNode): boolean {
    return true;
}

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    this.gridOptions = {
        editType: 'fullRow',
        columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
        pagination: true,
        animateRows: true,
        isExternalFilterPresent: this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this),
        doesExternalFilterPass: this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this),
    };
}

<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height:600px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    rowSelection='single' [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    (rowValueChanged)="onRowChanged($event)" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

very basic external filter implementation to ag-Grid

however when click the search button, the whole page direct to the previous page which is very weird and I am not able to debug.

Comment: Is there a reason you removed your button component from the example? I was looking at it , it refreshed, and now I don't see it after the edit. The reason I ask is because the default `type` attribute of the button is submit (which would cause your page to refresh or redirect) and the button you had did not have a `type` attribute defined.

Comment: @nullptr.t thanks, sorry my bad, I meant to edit it, not remove , just put it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not sure if it is the best way to resolve it, but I got it to work by returning a `false` to `applyFilter()`

```
applyFilter() {
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
    return false;   /// yea that fix it...
}
```

So @nullptr.t is right, the button is acting like submitting the form instead of button

Comment: You could also just set `type='button'` as the attribute on the html element. I believe this is the more common approach in Angular.